# Compile and upload to Arduino programmatically

Tags: c++, c, terminal, arduino, embedded

I know basic arduino development using the default Arduino IDE. I am using the Arduino Pro Mini 5V board for my project.

I need to be able to compile and upload the program onto the board programmatically (rather than using the buttons in the Arduino IDE). As an experiment, I have written a basic "blink LED" sample code that I want to be able to compile and then upload to the Arduino Pro Mini board - all programmatically - rather than through the default Arduino IDE.

How can I compile and upload the code to the Arduino Pro Mini through avrdude through a terminal rather than using the native Arduino IDE?

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// BLINK LED ON ARDUINO PRO MINI (5V)
//
// http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// For blinking an LED in arduino Pro Mini 5V
int blink_led = 13;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {          
    // Blink LED is an output pin.
    pinMode(blink_led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // BLINK LED
  digitalWrite(blink_led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(50);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(blink_led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(50);               // wait for a second
}
```

Comment: Hints: Use `makefile` for compilation (you can possibly use makefile from existing project or create a new one using IDE, if not familiar with Makefile structure.) & possibly `avrdude` or similar command line tool for uploading the program on the arduino.

Comment: the code you posted is totally irrelevant for your question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Ino](http://inotool.org/)?. It's a command line toolkit to build and upload Arduino sketches. They have a really good [Getting Started Guide](http://inotool.org/quickstart).

Answer (score 0):

[avrgirl](https://github.com/noopkat/avrgirl-arduino) is a library that might do what you want. Since I need to upload to ESP32, I'm going to try using [Arduino-CLI](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.28/) which seems to allow it.